# How to couple kafka with an object oriented database?

Tags: logging, apache-kafka, apache-nifi

I worked on an enterprise application which cannot be looked at as a relational database. Meaning, I cannot query it with a light weight SQL query nor do I have a ready to use connector with apache kafka.
I cannot poll this database or can I?
Iv looked through confluent open source options but did not find a plug in I could use.
I couldn't find a processor for an object oriented database on apache NIFI either
Can I poll from my logs assuming I have CRUD data in my logs? Does that make sense or am I overlooking something? 
Any suggestions please?

Comment: You might be able to watch the logs. That's what oracle GoldenGate or Debezium would do. Or you can attempt to add JDBC connectivity into your database via something like Apache Calcite (SQL queries don't imply relational databases)

Comment: Thank you @cricket_007.. Let me try it out..